# How do I properly restart a timeout in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a carousel of slides that I am rotating through at 5 second intervals.
I have a function that clears the timeout to stop the rotation.
I am trying to restart the carousel with the code below. The behavior works but incorrectly. Instead of resuming at 5 sec intervals it is quickly flashing through the slides.

```
t = setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
var interval;
$(document).on('mousemove keyup keypress',function(){
    clearTimeout(carousel);
    setTimeout(carousel, 6000);
})
```

Comment: You need to use `clearTimeout(t)`. `t` is an identifier for the timer. This is what you cancel, not the function `carousel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
t = setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
var interval;
$(document).on('mousemove keyup keypress',function(){
    clearTimeout(t /* instead of carousel */);
    t = setTimeout(carousel, 6000); // also refresh the value of the timeout
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are clearing timeout on inproper variable. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout#Parameters) it should be id of timeout so:

```
t = setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
$(document).on('mousemove keyup keypress',function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(carousel, 6000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
    clearTimeout(carousel);
```

is incorrect. `clearTimeout`'s argument isn't the callback function, it's the timeout's identifier returned by `setTimeout`. Should be something like

```
t = setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 

$(document).on(/* some events */,function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
});

$(document).on(/* some other events */,function(){
    t = setTimeout(carousel, 6000);
});
```